# Keep track of price and total cost

Tags: java

I'm trying to keep track of each items cost, and add that to the total cost of all the items. When I run the program the last item cost and total cost is applied to each item. I feel like I should have another loop more dynamically placing the cost of each item and total cost.

## Driver Class:

```
    public class GroceryListTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       GroceryList get = new GroceryList();
       get.start();
   }
}
```

## CheckMail Class:

```
import chn.util.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GroceryList
{
        //Instance variables
        private int myNumItems;
        private double myItemCost;
        private double myTotalCost;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Constructor
        public GroceryList()
        {
            myNumItems = 0;
            myTotalCost = 0;
        }
        //Methods
        public void start()
        {
            System.out.print('\u000C');
            getMyNumItems();
            getMyItemPrices();
            output();
        }
        public int getMyNumItems()
        {
            System.out.print("How many items would you like to purchase? => ");
            myNumItems = keyboard.nextInt();

            return myNumItems;
        }
        public double getMyItemPrices()
        {
            int n = 0; //Disp item number

            while(n  < myNumItems)
            {
                System.out.print("Please enter price of item #" +(n+1) +": ");
                myItemCost = keyboard.nextDouble();
                myTotalCost = myTotalCost + myItemCost;
                ++n;
            }

            return myTotalCost;
        }
        public void output()
        {
            for(int n = 0; n < myNumItems; ++n)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.printf("%8s %8s %8s", "Item #" +(n + 1) , "Cost: $" +myItemCost, "Total: $" +myTotalCost);

            }
        }
}
```

## Output:

```
How many items would you like to purchase? => 3
Please enter price of item #1: 1.25
Please enter price of item #2: 1.75
Please enter price of item #3: 1.50

 Item #1 Cost: $1.5 Total: $4.5
 Item #2 Cost: $1.5 Total: $4.5
 Item #3 Cost: $1.5 Total: $4.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not storing any reference to the price of any item but the last. This calls for a ArrayList keeping track of each item that has already been ordered.

If instead of using your int myItemCost, you used ArrayList< int> myItemCosts, and each time you added a new item you added the stated price to that List, you could print each of those items at the end.

Here's an example:

```
ArrayList<int> myItemCosts = new ArrayList<int>();
public double getMyItemPrices()
{
    int n = 0;

    while (n < myNumItems)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter price of item #" + (n+1) + ": ");
        myItemCosts.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
        myTotalCost += myItemCost;
    }
}
```

And then output() could be structured like so:

```
public void output()
{
    for(int n = 0; n < myNumItems; ++n)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%8s %8s %8s", "Item #" + (n + 1) , "Cost: $" + myItemCosts[n], "Total: $" + myTotalCost);
    }
 }
```

If you decided you needed to add more function to any given grocery item, like a SKU, quantity, discount, etc., you should create your own object to encapsulate these properties:

```
class SampleGroceryItem
{
    public SampleGroceryItem(double price, int quantity, string sku, double discount)
    {
        this.Price = price;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
        this.Sku = sku;
        this.Discount = discount;
    }

    public double Price;
    public int Quantity;
    public string Sku;
    public double Discount;
}
```

and then instantiate a new SampleGroceryItem each time the user inputs all the necessary information, and add that object to a List.